# Include Test Steps info in JUnit SoapUI reports

Tags: jenkins, junit, cucumber, soapui, ready-api

I am using SoapUI to execute tests and Ant to generate html report from xml to publish in Jenkins CI.
But html reports only shows the status of the testCases (http://www.luv2code.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/junit_report_screenshot-1024x567.png), does anyone knows how to include datailed step information(e.g. description and status) inside TestCases, similar to Cucumber reports like this? https://sakib.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/screen-shot-2015-10-25-at-9-12-03-pm1.png

Thank you very much.